# How to provide auto change for a QTimeEdit?

Tags: qt

I have a QTimeEdit widget on my dialog and I want to provide some kind of autochange - if the cursor is on minutes section and the time is 04:59, the next click on the arrow up would lead the time to change to 5:00.

How to do that?

I saw some mention of AutoAdvance property but I suppose it's obsolete because I cannot find it in Qt 4.7.

Comment: That feature disappeared between 3.3 and 4.0. It seems like it would have been a nice feature to keep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed there is a signal called `void timeChanged ( const QTime & time )`. You can connect it to a slot and call function `void QAbstractSpinBox::stepBy ( int steps )` in the slot function.

**EDIT1**:

Sorry for the misleading. In fact, we don't really need  `void timeChanged ( const QTime & time )`.
See the code below:

```
class myTime : public QTimeEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    virtual void stepBy(int steps)
    {
        if (this->time().minute()==59 && steps>0){
            setTime(QTime(time().hour()+1,0,time().second(),time().msec()));
        }else if(this->time().minute()==00 && steps<0){
            setTime(QTime(time().hour()-1,59,time().second(),time().msec()));
        }else{
            QTimeEdit::stepBy(steps);
        }
    }
};
```

Keep in mind, you need to `setWrapping(true)` yourself.

Comment: Sorry for delaying with the answer, but finally I tried your method. The problem is I need to response on the clicking of the arrow for example up, but not for changing of the time! Because it will never happen! For example the amount of seconds will not be more than 59. It means than if I truck the change of the time what time should I track to do StepBy()? 59? But 59 is only 59, I don't need to response to change from 58 to 59 and change 59 to 60 will never happen.

Comment: So now actually my question is how to response to the arrow clicks?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I've tried your code but and it works but the problem is when for example seconds amount is 59 and this section is selected (seconds) even if I click the arrow up nothing happens. For some reason stepBy is not called in this situation. Maybe I described the problem wrong - but what I need: when I stay on seconds if it's 59 and I click up seconds should be 0 and minute should be incremented by 1. But for some reason this method is not called when value is 59 and if I click arrow up.

Comment: The strange thing is QAbstractSpin has stepBy: "Note that this function is called even if the resulting value will be outside the bounds of minimum and maximum. It's this function's job to handle these situations." - from documentation but it seems to me developers changed the behaviour of the QtimeEdit.

Comment: That is because I only write the code when **minute** is 59. This is only an example code, and you should complete it yourself.

Comment: No, the problem is not in the code but in the widget itself. Even if the stepBy is empty it have never fired if amount is 59 now and I click the arrow up.

Comment: Did you use `setWrapping(true)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it's still interesting, but I found another solution:

```
class myTime : public QTimeEdit {
    Q_OBJECT public:
    virtual void stepBy(int steps)
    {
     long lFactor=1;
     if (currentSection()==QDateTimeEdit::MinuteSection)
      lFactor=60;
     else if (currentSection()==QDateTimeEdit::HourSection)
      lFactor=3600;

     long lDateTime = (dateTime().toMSecsSinceEpoch()/1000)+(steps*lFactor);
     QDateTime dt = QDateTime::fromMSecsSinceEpoch(1000*(qint64)(lDateTime));
     setDateTime(dt);     
    } };
```

Answer (score 0):

If some one is wondering how to automatically change time (because I did), and needs easy, rather clean solution, here's what I came up with:

```
class TimeWidget : public QTimeEdit {
      Q_OBJECT
      public:
      void stepBy(int steps) {
          //Grab the current time
          QTime t = time();

         //So we edit the time as in raw milliseconds. Larger type would be better in this case.
         //But 32bits is more than enough for day amount of milliseconds.
         int raw = (t.hour()*360000 + t.minute()*60000 + t.second() * 1000 + t.msec());

         //Let's find out what section time widget is changing
         //And edit the raw millisecond data accordingly. 
         switch(currentSection()) {
              case QDateTimeEdit::MSecSection:
                   raw += steps;
              break;
              case QDateTimeEdit::SecondSection:
                   raw += steps*1000;
              break;
              case QDateTimeEdit::MinuteSection:
                  raw+= steps*60000;
              break;
              case QDateTimeEdit::HourSection:
                 raw += steps*3600000;
              break;
       }

       //Now we just split the "raw" milliseconds into
       int hrs = (raw/ 36000000) % 24; //... hours
       int mins = (raw/ 60000) % 60; //... minutes
       int secs = (raw / 1000) % 60; //... seconds
       int mills = raw % 1000;  //... milliseconds

       //Update & save the current time
       t.setHMS(hrs, mins, secs, mills);
       setTime(t);
    }

};
```